# How to show tree structure in a grid in ASP.NET and C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to show a tree like structure associated with each row of grid like below picture. Whenever I click on + button of the row, some options should appear for that particular row.

Googled a lot but did not find anything fulfilling my requirement.

Please share your knowledge if you have done like this before.

[image]

Comment: did u check this http://highoncoding.com/Articles/422_Nested_GridView_with_TreeView_Like_Structure.aspx

Comment: @Nag - No demo is there and also download sample takes to other site which has no download option...

Comment: please check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/160773/Expandable-Rows-in-GridView

Comment: this one also: http://temebele.wordpress.com/2009/02/10/nested-editable-gridview-with-on-demand-data-binding/

Comment: @Nag - Thanks, codeproject link is useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got following links very useful for creating hierarchy of grids or grid into grid or expandable grids.

**Telerik:**

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/hierarchy/nestedviewtemplate/defaultcs.aspx

**DevEx**

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/MasterDetail/DetailTabs.aspx

**Codeproject** (with the help of Nag)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/160773/Expandable-Rows-in-GridView